# How can I make a custom post type be a pages parent in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm looking to make a series of pages have a parent of a custom post type I created. For Example, My custom post type `"Hospitals"` may have an entry of `"Some Hospital Name"` that entry may have several pages that have generic page content like `"contact us"`. I need this contact us page to have a slug of `"website.com/some-hospital-name/contact-us"` currently its `"website.com/contact-us"`.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your custom post type, you can specify it as `'hierarchical'` as part of its $args. If `'hierarchical'` is set to `true`, you also have to specify `'page-attributes'` in the `'supports'` argument in order to show the parent select box in the editor.

```
$args = array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'page-attriutes' )
);
```

See the register_post_type reference in the WordPress Codex:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

Comment: I think this is solving the opposite goal: a page as the parent of the post type. what they seem to be asking is for the post type to be the parent of the page instead.